# Struggling when converting PNG to ICO file?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Hi guys please help me i can't solve this, i have this image

[image]

When i try to convert it to ico using

```
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
png = Image.open("converter.png")
png.save("icon.ico", format='ICO',quality=100)
```

And i use the icon for a shortcut in the desktop the result is this

[image]

It's stretched to the top and the bottom. How to solve this and keep the same aspect ratio of the image? Thanks

It doesn't work even with

```
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
png = Image.open("converter.png")
png.resize((64,64), resample=0)
png.save("icon.ico", format='ICO',quality=100)
```

Comment: Simply add your image to this post as well. You may want to investigate if the convert params allow for settings to use when converting nonsquare sources to square icons. alternatively padd your image to square before you convert

Comment: Icons are always square.  All you need to do is pad your `png` so that it is square.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Hi now you can see the image in the post, please can you write me the code how to pad the image to be square before convert? Maybe a way that works with any image, thanks

Comment: @TimRoberts Hey thanks for the help, can you write me how to pad the png to be square, don't know how to do it maybe this is the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to resize the image to a square, but you don't want to stretch or compress the image.

You can create a new square image and place your original image in the center.

```
from PIL import Image
png = Image.open("converter.png")
size = png.size
ico = Image.new(mode="RGBA", size=(max(size), max(size)), color=(0, 0, 0, 0))
ico.paste(png, (int((max(size)-size[0])/2), int((max(size)-size[1])/2)))
ico.save("icon.ico", format='ICO', quality=100)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help i marked as accepted the answer and upvoted for now it works i tried with a couple of images, how did you figured out the solution? I mean how do you implemented this math in the line before saving the "ico"? It seems complicated

Comment: It's easy.  `size` has the size of your png as (width,height).  `max(size)` is the length of the longest side.  `max(size) - size[0]` is either 0 if this is the longest side, or the amount that the short side is short if not.  We divide by 2 so you get half the padding on top and half on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Image.resize(size, resample=0) function to make .ico file squared (equal width and height.

In your case it would look something like this:

```
png.resize((64,64), resample=0)
```

You can fiddle with resample argument to make it look better.

> resample – An optional resampling filter.

> This can be one of PIL.Image.NEAREST (use nearest neighbour), >PIL.Image.BILINEAR (linear interpolation), PIL.Image.BICUBIC (cubic
> spline interpolation), or PIL.Image.LANCZOS (a high-quality
> downsampling filter).

> If omitted, or if the image has mode “1” or “P”, it is set PIL.Image.NEAREST.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, i tried to implement your answer using                                                            
"from PIL import Image,ImageTk
png = Image.open("converter.png")
png.resize((64,64), resample=0)
png.save("icon.ico", format='ICO',quality=100)"  But its' the same result, am i doing it wrong? You can read the code better in the end of my original answer